# Access to redmine from PHP with JRedmine

Tags: php, redmine

I need to add attachments to issues in redmine 1.3 through Rest API using PHP. I found plugin JRedmine http://maven-site.nuiton.org/jredmine/. I managed to connect to genuine redmine API without problems but I don't know how to use JRedmine. Any help would be appreciated. I copied documentation of JRedmine here: http://alden.pl/jredmine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tonymarschall in fact you are not right. I can access JRedmine with PHP. Assuming redmine is available at http://redmine.myserver.com I can use curl and POST http://redmine.myserver.com/jredmine/login with params `username` and `password` and get an answer. I must setup cookie for curl to use others JRedmine functions after authentication.

All the API is described here: http://www.nuiton.org/embedded/jredmine/jredmine-client/rails_api.html (in french).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like JRedmine is a java programm. So you will not be able to use this through php. Try to use the rest api with php like it is described here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_php and here:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Attaching-files

Comment: The main problem is that it's 1.3 version and there may be problems with upgrading.